# Plural for fields_for has_many association not showing in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, fields-for

Currently, an **Item**  *belongs_to* a **Company** and *has_many* **ItemVariants**.

I'm trying to use nested fields_for to add ItemVariant fields through the Item form, however using :item_variants does not display the form. It is only displayed when I use the singular.

I have check my associations and they seem to be correct, could it possibly have something to do with item being nested under Company, or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

*Note: Irrelevant code has been omitted from the snippets below.*

**EDIT:** Don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using CanCan for Authentication.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :companies do
  resources :items
end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :sku, :item_type, :comments, :item_variants_attributes


  # Associations
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :item_type
  has_many   :item_variants

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_variants, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**item_variant.rb**

```
class ItemVariant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_id, :location_id

  # Associations
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  belongs_to :item

end
```

**item/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@company, @item] do |f| %>
  ...
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :item_variants do |builder| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= builder.label :location_id %>
      <%= builder.collection_select :location_id, @company.locations.order(:name), :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  ...
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should prepopulate `@item.item_variants` with some data:

```
def new # in the ItemController
  ...
  @item = Item.new
  3.times { @item.item_variants.build }
  ...
end
```

Source: http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly,, but as a reference I was using the RailsCast ep 196-Nested-model-form-revised. In his new action it only contained `@survey = Survey.new` with no building of the association. Any idea why I need to build the association and Ryan didn't/doesn't?

Comment: That railscast is even better, although complex, because it can dynamically add questions in the survey form. So it does not need to prepopulate anything.

Comment: I just wanted to add on some meaning for those who are confused about the .build and why Ryans' didn't need it. If you look at his code in appliation_helper on line 3 its creating the class instance. So that takes the place of .build. Hope this helps anyone else out there!

Answer (score 2):

try this way

in your `item controller`  `new action`  write

```
def new
  ...
    @item = # define item here
    @item.item_variants.build if @item.item_variants.nil?
  ...
end
```

and in `item/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  ...
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :item_variants do |builder| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
  ...
<% end %>
```

for more see video - [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Thanks. Got it working, but using `@item.item_variants.build if @item.item_variants.nil?` didn't work. It only works if i remove the if statement.
Also, Using that Revised version of your link was what confused me. In his controller he doesn't use .build. He only creates the @survey instance. Any idea why I need to build the association and Ryan didn't/doesn't?