# Rails4 Simple_form nested form field not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails and have scoured Stackoverflow and the internet to the best of my abilities and am still stumped.

In my set-up, a Rating belongs_to a Product and has_many Comments. I'm using simple-form and trying to use nested fields_for to add RatingComment through the Rating form. Interestingly, when using the singular form of :rating_comment, the field is displayed. But as expected, I get the unpermitted parameter error when trying to save. When I use plural :rating_comments, the field disappears. This is similar to this [SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987967/plural-for-fields-for-has-many-association-not-showing-in-view), but adding @rating.rating_comments.build to new action still does not work for me. I've tried restarting the server many times, and even reset the database to no avail. Would appreciate any assistance as I've been struggling with this issue for the past few days.

Note: I've also taken out what I think is irrelevant code from the snippets below. If I need to show more information, please do let me know. Thanks in advance!

routes.rb

```
resources :ratings, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  resources :rating_comments, shallow: true
end
```

rating.rb

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :rating_comments, foreign_key: "rating_id", dependent: :destroy      
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rating_comments, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

rating_comment.rb

```
class RatingComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rating
  validates :rating_id, presence: true
end
```

ratings_controller.rb

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :new, :show]

  def new
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @rating = @product.ratings.new
    @rating.rating_comments.build
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @rating = @product.ratings.build(rating_params)
    @rating.user_id = current_user.id
    ...

  private
    def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:user_id, :product_id, :rating,  rating_comments_attributes: [:rating_id, :content])
  end
end
```

ratings/_new_rating_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([@product, @rating], html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :rating, collection: 1..10, as: :radio_buttons, 
          item_wrapper_class: 'inline', checked: 5 %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :rating_comments do |rc| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= rc.input :content, label: "Comments" %>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.error :base %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very embarrassed to admit that it turns out that I had the view written in the wrong action. Once I put it in the new.html, it finally worked.