# undefined method `[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm very new to Rails and I'm honestly confused about what I'm doing, sorry for missing any basics here...

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156232/undefined-method-for-actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile0x007fae8c0bfaa8) did not help

Trying to upload a file from iOS client app via an API to my rails app hosted on Heroku.  Paperclip gem installed and file upload works great when using form.file_field upload.  But not from API.

```
undefined method `[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
```

When doing PUT method to upload file at /api/v1/foos/1

Model

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :foo_file
    validates_attachment : foo_file, content_type: { content_type: ["application/xml"] }

end
```

Controller

```
class Api::V1::FoosController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def update

    result = { status: "failed" }

    begin
      params[:foo_file] = parse_foo_file_data(params[:foo_file]) if params[:foo_file]
      item = Foo.find(params[:id])
      item.foo_file = params[:foo_file]

      if item.save
        result[:status] = "success"
      end

    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.error "#{e.message}"
    end

    ensure
      clean_tempfile

    foo = Foo.find(params[:id])

    authorize foo

    if !foo.update_attributes(update_params)
      return api_error(status: 422, errors: foo.errors)
    end

    render json: result.to_json

  end

  def parse_foo_file_data(foo_file_data)
    @tempfile = Tempfile.new('item_foo_file')
    @tempfile.binmode
    @tempfile.write Base64.decode64(foo_file_data.read)
    @tempfile.rewind

    uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
      tempfile: @tempfile,
      original_filename: foo_file_data.original_filename
    )

    uploaded_file.content_type = foo_file_data.content_type
    uploaded_file
  end

  def clean_tempfile
    if @tempfile
      @tempfile.close
      @tempfile.unlink
    end
  end

  def update_params
   params.require(:app).permit(
     :name, :user_id, :foo_file
     )
  end
end
```

Ultimately I would appreciate any assistance in getting this file uploaded and attached to the foo_file parameter of the foo object.  I think it has to do with the undefined method error that I pointed out.  Or I might just be totally off base.  Thank you for your time and help!

EDIT:

New server logs

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/foos/1

Processing by Foo::V1::FoosController#update as JSON

Parameters: 
{"foo"=>{"name"=>"newnameB"}, "foo_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fac81c82168 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160523-6-q6pyac.xml>, @original_filename="Main.xml", @content_type="multipart/form-data", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foo_file\"; filename=\"Main.xml\"\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\n">, "id"=>"1"}

undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

Comment: You have a space here that broke it I think. " :name, :user_id, : foo_file" should be " :name, :user_id, :foo_file"

Comment: Sorry, that's me just translating names incorrectly into 'foo'.  There's no space in my actual code.  I've edited the post.  Thanks for the attention to detail.

Answer (score 0):

Near the beginning of `update`, on this line:

```
params[:foo_file] = parse_foo_file_data(params[:foo_file]) if params[:foo_file]
```

you call `pase_foo_file_data(params[:foo_file])`. You can see if the log, `params[:foo_file]` is an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object.

Down below, `parse_foo_file_data` is defined like this:

```
def parse_foo_file_data(foo_file_data)
    @tempfile = Tempfile.new('item_foo_file')
    @tempfile.binmode
    @tempfile.write Base64.decode64(foo_file_data[:data])
    @tempfile.rewind
    # ... etc
```

On the third line of that, you have `foo_file_data[:data]`. But `foo_file_data` is an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object, and [that class doesn't provide a `[]` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).

It seems like what you most likely are trying to do is get the data out of the UploadedFile object, in which case you'd want something more along the lines of `@tempfile.write Base64.decode64(foo_file_data.read)`

You'll run into a similar problem when you try to call `foo_file_data[:content_type]` further down, that needs to be `foo_file_data.content_type`.

Comment: That was actually great advice and it got rid of the error I was having.  But the file still won't upload to the foo object and I get a 'failed' response.  But now there's a different error in the logs.  Does anyone see something additionally wrong with the code?  Should I accept this answer and then post the question again?

Comment: There's no direct call to `gsub` in the code you've pasted, so it's not really possible to tell what's happened from just the information provided. You may want to log the exception backtrace rather than (or in addition to) the message, e.g. `e.backtrace`.

Comment: Also I've only just noticed, but you _really_ [shouldn't ever rescue `Exception`](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/28/why-you-should-never-rescue-exception-in-ruby/), that will rescue things like NoMemoryException or SystemStackError. The broadest error you should ever intercept is StandardError, unless you have a very good reason.