# Why do I get "undefined method `[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:" when trying to upload an image while updating model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails, and have been developing a slide-sharing application with some complex functionality.

I talk about four models: Spark, Question, Answer, and AnswerImage.

Spark has_many Questions, Question has_many Answers, and Answer has_many AnswerImages. And of course AnswerImages belongs_to Answer and so on.

I use a nested form to update a Question and add a new Answer simultaneously. An instance of Answer may or may not contain an AnswerImage (I use Carrierwave to upload the attachments to S3). When I try and upload an image to the Answer, I get the following error: `undefined method '[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile: ... >`. If I don't try to attach an image, the Question is updated and an answer is created smoothly.

Here is my code:

1. QuestionsController's update action and question_params

   ```
   class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def update
       @spark = Spark.find(params[:spark_id])
       @question = @spark.questions.find(params[:id])
       if @question.update(question_params) # This is where the extracted source of the error is!
           flash[:success] = "The question was successfully updated!"
           redirect_to @spark
       else
           render 'edit'
       end
   end

   private
   def question_params
       params.require(:question).permit(:id, :name, :email, :body, :slide_number, :authorized, :tag_list,
           :answers_attributes => [:id, :content, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :imgNo, :path, 
           :answer_images_attributes => [:loc, :id] ]
       )
   end
   end
   ```
2. The Question update form

   ```
   <%= form_for :question, :method => :patch, :url => "/sparks/#{@spark.id}/questions/#{@question.id}" do |f| %>
       <p>
           Question Fields
       </p>

       <%= f.fields_for :answers_attributes do |answer_builder| %>
           <div class="form-group"> 
               <%= answer_builder.hidden_field :id %>
               <%= answer_builder.label "Answer (If you want to include an image in the answer, navigate to the page you want, and double click anywhere on the page)"%><br>
               <%= answer_builder.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', style: 'width: 100%;' %>
               <p>
                   <%= answer_builder.fields_for :answer_images_attributes, html: {multipart: true} do |image| %>
                       <%= image.file_field :loc %>
                   <% end %>
               </p>
           </div>
       <% end %>

       <p>
           <%= f.submit "Save Question", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
       </p>
   <% end %>
   ```
3. Logs

   ```
   Started PATCH "/sparks/13/questions/13" for ::1 at 2016-07-12 11:16:34 -0400
   Processing by QuestionsController#update as HTML
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mCGLm1Aw2TQo05eVNxFMy/5DxpeRCtpc58tRCX/pt0AEQ1yyMSH7qUxXH3VYXDgDt9T6KTz0Zx9v9mMprroAXw==", "question"=>{"email"=>"rohit.k.gupte@gmail.com", "tag_list"=>"all, ", "slide_number"=>"1", "body"=>"sadf", "answers_attributes"=>{"id"=>"", "content"=>"Answer", "answer_images_attributes"=>{"loc"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe215f6efb0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/8z/tjjy3sd507j1m3w4mrsbtjk00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160712-769-3q9ssg.jpg>, @original_filename="GSWImage584.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"question[answers_attributes][answer_images_attributes][loc]\"; filename=\"GSWImage584.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "authorized"=>"1"}, "answer_image"=>"on", "commit"=>"Save Question", "spark_id"=>"13", "id"=>"13"}
     Spark Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "sparks".* FROM "sparks" WHERE "sparks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
     Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."spark_id" = ? AND "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["spark_id", 13], ["id", 13]]
      (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

   NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe215f6efb0>):
     app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:53:in `update'
   ```
4. Question model

   ```
   class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :spark
     has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

     acts_as_taggable_on :tags

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['content'].blank? }
   end
   ```
5. Answer model

   ```
   class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :question

     has_many :answer_images, dependent: :destroy

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_images, :allow_destroy => true
   end
   ```
6. AnswerImage model

   ```
   class AnswerImage < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :answer

     mount_uploader :loc, AnswerPngStore, dependent: :destroy
   end
   ```

I can provide code for the Uploader if needed although I don't think the problem lies there.

I have taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156232/undefined-method-for-actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile0x007fae8c0bfaa8) post and a few others that describe different undefined method errors for ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, but none of them had a conclusive solution.

I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: add you models pls

Comment: Added the Question, Answer and AnswerImage models

Comment: Hi @Rohit! Did you ever find a fix for this problem? Encountering something similar on my end, curious to learn what the issue is... Thanks!